# How to get innerDOM of polymer custom element?

Tags: polymer

I have a polymer custom element like below

```
<custom-element>
  <img src="path1">
  <img src="path2">
  <img src="path3">
  <img src="path4">
</custom-element>
```

Now I want to display each image in a separate `div`

I tried like this in the `custom-element` template

```
<div class="image-wrapper">
   <content select="img"></content>
</div>
```

The above code making all images in single div that is `image-wrapper` as shown below

```
<div class="image-wrapper">
  <img src="path1">
  <img src="path2">
  <img src="path3">
  <img src="path4">
</div>
```

But I want each image in individual `image-wrapper` as shown below

```
<div class="image-wrapper">
  <img src="path1">
</div>
<div class="image-wrapper">
  <img src="path2">
</div>
<div class="image-wrapper">
  <img src="path3">
</div>
<div class="image-wrapper">
  <img src="path4">
</div>
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

As a quick answer,

```
<custom-element>
  <img src="path1">
</custom-element>
<custom-element>
  <img src="path2">
</custom-element>
<custom-element>
  <img src="path3">
</custom-element>
<custom-element>
  <img src="path4">
</custom-element>
```

You'll probably wrap it like this,

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[paths]]" as="path">
    <custom-element>
      <img src="[[path]]">
    </custom-element>
</template>
```

Assuming paths is an array.

```
paths = [
    "path1",
    "path2",
    "path3",
    "path4",
];
```